# Stewart section 10.2 problem 24: isn't this curve undefined?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

The problem reads:

Find parametric equations for the tangent line to the curve with the given parametric equations at the specified point: $x = \ln(t), y = 2\sqrt{t}, z = t^2$; $(0, 2,1)$.

It seems to me that, since $x = \ln(t)$, the curve is not *defined* at any point where $t = 0$. Am I missing something obvious? Is there some way of defining the tangent line to the curve at a point even when the curve is not defined there?

Comment: At the point $(0,2,1)$ the parameter $t$ is $1$: $\ln(1) = 0$.

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks.